# Apache .htaccess block access by IP but allow all for certain URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've successfully blocked access to my private site using `.htaccess` with the following:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://error.redirect.com

# Stripe webhook IP's
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx(,| |$)" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx(,| |$)" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx(,| |$)" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xx\.xxx\.xx\.xx(,| |$)" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xx\.xxx\.xx\.xxx(,| |$)" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xx\.xxx\.xx.\xxx(,| |$)" AllowIP

# PayPal Sandbox IPN IP's
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xxx\.x\.xx\.xxx(,| |$)" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "(,| |^)xxx\.x\.xx\.xx(,| |$)" AllowIP


Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowIP
```

But I need to be able to allow certain URL's complete public access. How can I bypass this IP restriction for specific URL's?